# Is there a way to run code from an Iphone app to another Iphone App?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, cordova

So I know that we can use URL schemes to OPEN an app from an app, but that's not my objective.

Say I want to make an Iphone app which users can download and click a button which will launch another app ( eg.gmail for this case) and run some sort of front-end actions. For example, make the icons bigger, change colors, change the UI, highlight stuff, add pop-up text, etc. Just to re-terate, I'm not trying to modify any code on the gmail app it self. I want to code my app to do certain actions that can be "applied" or "faked" in the view of the other app.

I was thinking there could be a virtual button ideally (like the virtual assist on the iphone) that would popup on the gmail app. I'm not trying to change any functionalities or gmail's code, just want to to be able to modify the front-end experience.

Chrome extensions are easy to use in this case since you can open any site and change anything once user launches extension on the page, but is there something similar to IOS?

Comment: No.  The sandbox prevents you for manipulating another app. To be able to do so would be an enormous privacy and security issue because it would mean that you could change the compiled code of that other app. 99.9999999% of iOS apps are not written using web technologies so you couldn't just manipulate a DOM or CSS. Also iOS has a comprehensive set of accessibility features that let the user change display magnification, font sizes, colour etc.

Comment: hmmm interesting. So bascially, I don't want to "manipulate" the code in any way. I just want to give it a fake feeling that something is happening. For example, the gmail front-end code it self wouldn't change at all. I would just like to pop a text box or a graphic arrow and point to somewhere in the gmail app. Or say highlight a section. It won't actually change anything in gmail but in the user's screen, the mail would seem highlighted. Am I making sense

Comment: Yes,  but that would require changing the code, since the screen is rendered by code. At the very least you would be manipulating the memory of the other app. There is no rendering layer or engine that you can manipulate. Let's say you could. This would allow you to insert a text box asking for a password, which the user would trust since it is in the gmail app, but which you controlled. You see how this would be bad. Sandboxing is a fundamental part of iOS security

Comment: yes I completely understanding the fundamental IOS security aspect. I guess I'm still confused as to how this may work with normal html websites. I've seen alot of chrome extensions where they are able to "change" the front-end of a website. There's extensions that say, darken a screen or change a font. So is it safe to conclude that all that can be done if I make a Chrome extension but it won't work within IOS apps? or Android apps? Like your example about text-box for password, I can do that on the web as well for gmail/facebook? How does security work then?

Comment: It doesn’t. The level of security in ios  vs the level of security in the web is several orders of magnitude higher. If you run an extension in Chrome you are effectively surrendering your security to the level of trust you put in the extension developer. The browsers try and put controls in to mitigate risks but there are no guarantees. Also the fundamental presentation layer of a web site is completely different to a mobile app. There is no CSS or HTML in most cases. Just compiled code

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't run code from an app to another app. An app is like a sandbox and each sandbox is isolated from one to another.

Comment: please see edited question. No trying to change any code. Still not possible?

Comment: use the other app's SDK.

Comment: can you elaborate? How the process would work, for say a facebook sdk? Can it work if I use react to make an iphone app?